# Was Agent 33 designed with this villain in mind?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

As of the latest episode of Marvel's Agents of SHIELD ("Love in the Time of HYDRA"), former HYDRA operative Agent 33 is hanging out with Ward and now has

> the ability to change her face at will, using the repaired nano-mask to scan any face - male or female - and look like them. Her origin is very similar to the character [Madam Masque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_Masque) in the comics, with her disfigured face hidden by a mask.

Has anyone involved with the show mentioned this connection? It seems to fit with the MCU interpretation of comic characters so far.

Comment: There has been speculation of this, but I've yet to read anything official from Marvel or the studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of *Love in the Time of HYDRA* Agent 33 introduces herself to Ward as Kara.

Revealing she is the same [Kara Lynn Palamas](http://marvel.wikia.com/Kara_Lynn_Palamas_%28Earth-616%29) from the comics, who is named Agent 33.

However,

> when Talbot found out she infiltrated his base he called her a "damn mask".  [TvTropes WMG - Agents of SHIELD](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WMG/AgentsOfShield)

Possibly alluding to her eventually taking on the persona Madam Masque.

[image]

For more speculation check out http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WMG/AgentsOfShield

Comment: I didn't really see it as Talbot calling *her* a "damn mask" - more that he was cursing the mask itself.